# Task with result unknown type

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I'm working on a async CQS API

The WebAPi method looks like this

```
public async Task<object> Get([FromUri] Contract contract)
{
    return  await _invoker.Invoke(CreateDto<Query>(contract));
}
```

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   '`System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Customer>>`'
>   to '`System.Threading.Tasks.Task<object>`

How can I return a task from result without knowing the type?

This is the code that invokes the Generic typed class

```
public Task<object> Invoke(Query query)
{
    var queryHandlerType = typeof(IQueryHandler<,>);
    var queryType = query.GetType();
    var queryResultType = queryType.BaseType.GetGenericArguments().First();
    var handler = _container.GetInstance(queryHandlerType.MakeGenericType(queryType, queryResultType)) as dynamic;
    return handler.Handle(query as dynamic);
}
```

**edit:** Is there any reason why WebApi does not support `Task<T>` exposed as Task? If I change from Task to just plain Task it does not work. Its still a Task underneath so WebApi should be able to resolve that with some magic? I want todo this

```
public Task Get([FromUri] Contract contract)
{
    return _invoker.Invoke(CreateDto<Query>(contract));
}
```

Comment: right now it returns a Task<object> which also needs to be updated, see update for invoker code

Comment: Is there any reason it's been declared to return `Task<object>` vs a plain old `Task`?

Comment: You cant have return values? WebApi does nto display anything when doing it like that

Comment: The error message suggests `_invoker.Invoke` returns a `Task<IEnumerable<Customer>>` but your `Invoke` code returns a `Task<object>`. Where does that type come from? You should just be able to upcast the result to `object` after you await the task.

Comment: Can you not cast the return value as an object? Sorry, I can't replicate easily in a console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a little confusing. It's particularly not clear where the error message is coming from. Based on the little code you posted, the only thing I see that would make sense is that you're actually getting that error message at the `return` statement of your `Invoke()` method. I.e. that `handler.Handle(query as dynamic)` returns an object of type `Task<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Customer>>`. This, of course, would not be the same as `Task<object>` and so would be illegal.

If I understand correctly, then it seems to me you could address the issue by changing your `Invoke()` method itself to be `async`, so that you can rewrap the eventually-returned `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Customer>` object in the `Result` of a `Task<object>` instead of the `Task<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Customer>>` that is currently being generated:

```
public async Task<object> Invoke(Query query)
{
    var queryHandlerType = typeof(IQueryHandler<,>);
    var queryType = query.GetType();
    var queryResultType = queryType.BaseType.GetGenericArguments().First();
    var handler = _container.GetInstance(queryHandlerType.MakeGenericType(queryType, queryResultType)) as dynamic;
    return await handler.Handle(query as dynamic);
}
```

If that does not address your specific concern, please edit the question so that it is more clear. Please provide [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem.

Comment: This works, and its actually the same answer as Solal Pirellis. Whats the inpact of wrapping it like that? Will it result in a sync task that just casts the  old result to object? Is there a reason why WebAPI do not handle nonegeneric Tasks that are actual Task<T>?

Comment: I'll mark this as answer, but my actual question is if I can make WebApi work with Task<T> exposed as Task, new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29769261/return-taskt-as-plain-task-breaks-webapi

Comment: _"Whats the inpact of wrapping it like that"_ -- I would say "minimal". The operation is still asynchronous, it's just that the continuation is implemented one level down in the call stack. You do wind up with the intermediate `Task` object, but I see that as inevitable specifically because of the problem: you are required (apparently) to return an async `object` from the predefined API, but your underlying API returns a specific type. At some point, the specific type has to be unwrapped and rewrapped in the appropriate `Task<object>` type. The extra object is minimal overhead.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem here is that `Task<T>` is not covariant, i.e. you can't implicitly convert a `Task<Something>` to a `Task<object>` - unlike, for instance, the conversion from an `IEnumerable<Something>` to an `IEnumerable<object>`.

The easiest way to fix this is to change your `Get` method to `await` the task and return the value in two separate statements, like this:

```
object obj = await ...;
return obj;
```