# Return Task<T> as plain Task breaks WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await

This is actually a different angel on this question

[Task with result unknown type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29766333/task-with-result-unknown-type/29766709#29766709)

Consider this code

```
public interface IQueryHandler<in TQuery, TResult> where TQuery : Query<TResult>
{
    Task<TResult> Handle(TQuery query);
}
```

Above interface is invoked like where `Task<T>` will be exposed as `Task`

```
public Task Invoke(Query query)
{
    var queryHandlerType = typeof(IQueryHandler<,>);
    var queryType = query.GetType();
    var queryResultType = queryType.BaseType.GetGenericArguments().First();
    var handler = _container.GetInstance(queryHandlerType.MakeGenericType(queryType, queryResultType)) as dynamic;
    return handler.Handle(query as dynamic);
}
```

WebApi controller

```
public Task Get([FromUri] Contract contract)
{
    return _invoker.Invoke(CreateDto<Query>(contract));
}
```

This will break WebAPI and it will for some reason response redirect me to base url of site

Comment: That is odd that you're getting redirected. You're effectively returning void (asynchronously), which should result in a 204 (no content). Are you certain that the action is getting hit? Could verify by putting a breakpoint in your `Get` method and hitting it from the debugger.

Comment: Yupp, it hits both from Queryhandler and get method

Answer (score 0):

It does seem odd that you're getting a redirect response rather than a 204, but either way your action method isn't going to behave as you expect with that method signature. By returning a `Task`, you're effectively telling the framework you want to (asynchronously) return nothing.

I understand you don't know the `T` in `Task<T>` at runtime here, and the way to work around that is to await the result and cast it to an object. This should work:

```
public async Task<object> Get([FromUri] Contract contract)
{
    var result = await _invoker.Invoke(CreateDto<Query>(contract));
    return result as object;
}
```

Comment: Yes but in a framework that support declarations like 'public dynamic GetFoo() {}' you do expect it to resolve a Task to a Task<T> :D It does have alot of automagic for other stuff like mentioned dynamic but also JObject > static type etc. Seems strange it does not work here. Feels not very effecient to wrap it in yet another async task.

Comment: I disagree about the expectation. It's well documented that returning `void` or `Task` is how you explicitly signal to the framework that you want to return a no-content response. Inferring my intent entirely from the method signature (not the implementation) keeps things predictable and consistent imo.

Comment: Quirks like these are made all the time , another example is in Linq Count. it checks if IEnumerable is a List and uses the Count property if thats the case

Comment: This isn't a quirk though. Returning `Task` is an explicit mechanism for telling the framework you *want* the response body to be empty. If you don't, then you simply return `Task<T>` or `Task<object>` as I demonstrated. I'm not sure I understand your objection to that.

Comment: Well IEnumerable is to List what Task is to Task<T> (A superset)